# Get facts when var defined in hostvars

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

`ansible 2.9.1`

I have `inventory`:

```
[group1]
server1 master=yes
server2 master=no
server3 master=no
```

How get `ansible_fqdn` with `master=yes` from `server2`, `server3`?

Example:

`server2` or `server3` facts:

```
...
master_server: server1
...
```

I think so, but it did not work:

```
- name: set fact
  set_fact:
    master_server: {{ ansible_fqdn }}
  when: master == 'yes'
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
```

**UPDATE. RESOLVE**

add:

```
run_once: True
```

Comment: Simply change the order of your hosts in the group (which could happen for whatever reason...) and your solution totally breaks. Not mentionning the fact that you could have several masters in your group (i.e. by region or by environment).

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"How to get ansible_fqdn with master=yes from server2, server3?"*

A: There are more options. For example, either use `selectattr`

```
- hosts: group1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        master_server: "{{ (groups.group1|
                            map('extract', hostvars)|
                            selectattr('master', 'eq', True)|
                            list|
                            first).ansible_fqdn }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: master_server
```

, or use `json_query`

```
- hosts: group1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        master_server: "{{ groups.group1|
                           map('extract', hostvars)|
                           list|
                           json_query('[?master].ansible_fqdn')|
                           first }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: master_server
```

Both options give

```
ok: [test_02] => {
    "master_server": "test_01.example.org"
}
ok: [test_01] => {
    "master_server": "test_01.example.org"
}
ok: [test_03] => {
    "master_server": "test_01.example.org"
}
```

---

Inventory used in the examples

```
$ cat hosts
group1:
  hosts:
    test_01:
      master: yes
      ansible_fqdn: test_01.example.org
    test_02:
      master: no
      ansible_fqdn: test_02.example.org
    test_03:
      master: no
      ansible_fqdn: test_03.example.org
```